# How to replace deep values of an object?

Tags: javascript

Following is an object with deep props.

How can I replace the values of following prop

```
name: 'name'
```

with :

```
name: 'replaced_name'
```

```
const sample_object = {
    prop1: {
        subprop1: {
            anothersubprop1: {
                properties: {
                    deepProp1: {
                        name: 'name' 
                    }
                },
                '$ref': {

                },
                name: 'name'
            }
        }
    },
        prop2: {
        subprop1: {
            anothersubprop1: {
                properties: {
                    deepProp1: {
                        name: 'name' 
                    }
                },
                '$ref': {

                },
                name: 'name'
            },
            name: 'name'
        },
                subprop2: {
            anothersubprop1: {
                properties: {
                    deepProp1: {
                        name: 'name' 
                    },
                    deepProp2: {
                        name: 'name' 
                    }
                },
                '$ref': {

                },
                name: 'name'
            },
                        anothersubprop2: {
                properties: {
                    deepProp1: {
                        name: 'name' 
                    },
                    deepProp2: {
                        name: 'name' 
                    }
                },
                '$ref': {

                },
                name: 'name'
            },

            name: 'name'
            ...
        }
    },
}
```

Expected result:

```
const sample_object = {
    prop1: {
        subprop1: {
            anothersubprop1: {
                properties: {
                    deepProp1: {
                        name: 'replaced_name' 
                    }
                },
                '$ref': {

                },
                name: 'replaced_name'
            }
        }
    },
        prop2: {
        subprop1: {
            anothersubprop1: {
                properties: {
                    deepProp1: {
                        name: 'replaced_name' 
                    }
                },
                '$ref': {

                },
                name: 'replaced_name'
            },
            name: 'replaced_name'
        },
                subprop2: {
            anothersubprop1: {
                properties: {
                    deepProp1: {
                        name: 'replaced_name' 
                    },
                    deepProp2: {
                        name: 'replaced_name' 
                    }
                },
                '$ref': {

                },
                name: 'replaced_name'
            },
                        anothersubprop2: {
                properties: {
                    deepProp1: {
                        name: 'replaced_name' 
                    },
                    deepProp2: {
                        name: 'replaced_name' 
                    }
                },
                '$ref': {

                },
                name: 'replaced_name'
            },

            name: 'replaced_name'
            ...
        }
    },
}
```

**If lodash or any other similar library is possible, please suggest** 
**or any custom code**

Answer (score 2):

You can change the object to string then replace the old value with the new, after that use `JSON.parse` to make the string as an object again

example:

```js
let str = JSON.stringify(sample_object)
str = str.replace(/"name":"name"/g, '"name":"replaced_name"') // g -> for replace all the occurrences of the `name: name`
console.log(JSON.parse(str))
```

Comment: This method works well if the object and its children do not contain functions.  If they do, go with a recursive approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a recursive helper

```
import _ from 'lodash'

const = deepReplaceRecursive(old, new, obj) = {
  const new = _.clone(obj);

  _.each(object, (val, key) => {
    if (val === old) {
      // replace val if it's equal to the old value
      newObj[key] = new;
    } else if (typeof(val) === 'object' || typeof(val) === 'array') {
      // if val has nested values, make recursive call
      newObj[key] = deepReplaceRecursive(old, new, val);
    }
  });

  return newObj;
}

const object = { ... }
const newObject = deepReplaceRecursive("name", "replaceName", object)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lodash, `_.cloneDeepWith()` can recursively replace values:

```js
const newObject = _.cloneDeepWith(sampleObject, (value, key) => {
  if (key === "name" && value === "name") {
    return "replaced_name";
  }
  return undefined;
});
```